# How to calculate probabilities for Gold Lotto?

Tags: gambling, lotteries

For my assignment, I am trying to calculate the probabilities of Australian Saturday [Gold Lotto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TattsLotto) (45 balls, 6 winning, 2 supplementary).  I need help finding the division calculations to find the division odds (this must use combinations).
gold lotto: div 1 = 6 winning, div 2 = 5 winning numbers + 1 or 2 supplementary, div 3 = 5 winning numbers, div 4 = 4 winning div 5 = 3 winning+ 1 or 2 supplementary, div 6 = 1 or 2 winning numbers + 2 supplementary numbers.
The odds should end up being div 1 = 8145060:1, div 2 = 678755:1, div 3 = 36689:1, div 4 = 733:1 , div 5 = 297:1, div 6 = 144:1
(div 1 & 2 already done)
I have tried several variations of div 1 = 45c7
div 2 = (45c7 / (7c6 x (38c1 - 36c1)))
div 3 = (45c7 / (7c6 x 36c1))
div 4 = (45c7 / (7c5 x (38c2 - 36c2)))
div 5 = (45c7 / (7c5 x 36c2))
div 6 = (45c7 / (7c4 x 38c3))
div  = (45c7 / (7c3 x (38c4 - 36c4)))
(these equations are from oz lotto which is similar to gold lotto)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [lottery calculations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2295545/lottery-calculations)

Comment: @Max: The previous question had very sparse information, and no attempt, so remained unsolved.

Comment: @trueblueanil At the time that I closed voted, I wanted this post closed since OP simply reposted his previous question without any improvement. I was hoping someone would explain to OP that they're expected to improve their previous post and not simply repost it. BTW OP, high rep users have access to deleted questions and this kind of behavior could have consequences.

Comment: @Max: Oh, I didn't notice that the same OP has reposted (but with some sort of attempt), whereas s(he) should have added the material in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, odds against means ratio of **unfavorable outcomes:favorable outcomes**, whereas  what are apparently being computed is **total outcomes:favorable outcomes** i.e. $\dfrac{1}{p}$.

So I am also using $\dfrac{1}{p}$ while commenting.

**Div 1:** This is relatively simple,$6$ from winners and none from the rest, thus $\dfrac{\binom{45}6}{\binom66\binom{39}0} = 8145060:1$

**Div 2:** Not possible, if you have $5$ winning, you can't have $5$ winning and $2$ supplementary.

**Div 3 and Div 4:** You can do similar to **Div 1**

**Div 5:** There are $6$ winning, $2$ supplementary and $37$ others

Winners can be chosen in $\binom63$ ways, and *at least* one supplementary in $\binom{39}3 -\binom {37}3$ ways,

thus $\dfrac{\binom{45}{6}}{\binom63 \left[\binom{39}3 -\binom{37}3\right]} = 297:1$

You should be able to solve whatever else remains in similar fashion.

---

**Added for Div 2**

If the questioner wants you to ignore the possibility of $5$ winners and $2$ supplementary (which is impossible), and thus reduce the question to $5$ winners, and **one** supplementary, the answer is $\dfrac{\binom{45}{6}}{\binom65\binom21\binom{37}0} = 678755:1$

Comment: Is p permutation or something else?

Comment: *p* has been used for probability, i.e. (favorable outcomes)/(total outcomes)

Comment: where has the 456 from div 5 come from?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. Corrected.

Comment: @SomeRandomAwesomeGuy: So you are still not satisfied ?

Comment: just making sure before i place a tick, that it all works